# Finding the probability of a random variable given its expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'm taking the [Algorithms: Design and Analysis II](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms2+SelfPaced/about) class, one of the questions asks:

> Suppose $ X $ is a random variable that has expected value $ 1 $.
>
> a) What is the probability that $ X $ is $ 2 $ or larger? (Choose the
> strongest statement that is guaranteed to be true.)
>
> - At most $ 100\% $
> - At most $ 25\% $
> - $ 0 $
> - At most $ 50\% $
>
> b) Does the answer change if $ X $ is always nonnegative?

This is not an active homework question. I've completed the course successfully, but I don't like loose ends, hence going back and trying to solve the problems that I couldn't answer at that time.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you eliminate some of the proposed statements?

Comment: How is asking for the answers going back and solving the problems?

Comment: @lulu No, I can't.

Comment: @JohnDouma There's a thing called "understanding". It helps.

Comment: Really?  Surely you can eliminate the case $P(X≥2)=0$.  Just try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part $b$, using [Markov's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) we have
$$P(X\geq 2)\leq \frac{E[X]}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

For part $a$, consider the discrete random variable defined by
$$P(X=2)=.9$$
$$P(X=-8)=.1$$
Then $E(X)=1$ yet $P(X\geq 2)=.9$. This counterexample eliminates the second, third, and fourth options. So it must be the (trivial) first option: "at most $100\%"$

Comment: Is there a way to prove part a formally, without using a counterexample? The thing with counterexamples is, they are only as good as the person providing them. Who's to say there isn't a counterexample that invalidates option 1, and none of the answers are correct? (in other words, we seem to be cheating a little knowing the fact that one of the four options must be correct; how'd you proceed if only the question was given, not the options).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, a counterexample is perfectly valid here. And there can be no counterexample for option $1$, since obviously no probability can be higher than 100%

Comment: A counterexample is valid, but not proven to be exhaustive. What if a tighter bound, say 90% exists?

Comment: Your question says "Choose the strongest statement that is guaranteed to be true."  My counterexample shows that "0", "at most 25%" and "at most 50%" are not guaranteed to be true. Since "at most 100%" is *always* true, it is the only possible answer for part (a).

Comment: Agreed, which is why I accepted and upvoted your answer. However, I'm curious if a more formal treatment is possible to, "Prove the tightest possible bound"

Comment: There is no tightest possible bound. You can easily modify my counterexample to prove this. Say P(X=2)=.99, or .9999. Can you find x such that P(X=x)= .01 (or .0001), so that E(X) will still be 1?

Comment: My above comment should read "1 is the tightest possible bound" rather than "there is no tightest possible bound". What I meant to say is that you cannot come up with a bound that is strictly less than $1$